# Protractor, it is possible to get a result from it ()

Tags: jasmine, protractor

My code has an `it` with several `expect` conditions:

```
it (' xxxx', function (){

expect ().toBe(): 
expect ().toMatch(): 
expect ().toBe(): 
expect ().toMatch(): 
expect ().toBe(): 
expect ().toMatch(): 

});
```

The `it` will pass if all `expect` pass.

It is possible to do an `if` using the `it` as condition? 
I want to catch result of the test, `it`, to send to to TestRail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with testrail-promisse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to actually get the result of an it function. But you could store the result in a variable which is declared at beginning of spec file as follows:

```
describe('when testing site xxx', function() {
  var firstItSuccess = false;

  afterAll(function() {
    // send data to test rail after test..
    if(!firstItSuccess) {
      sendResultToTestRail(firstItSuccess);
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  });

  it('should load contents', function() {

    var ecpectedText = getExpectedText();
    var currentText = getCurrentText();
    firstItSuccess = expectedText === currentText;
    expect(firstItSuccess).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have to set that variavel per expect?   
like 
    if (expect ().tobe()){
    firstItSuccess = true;
} else {
    firstItSuccess  = false;
    }

Comment: I do not know a way to retrieve to value of `expect` but like this you achieve the same. I adjusted the answer.

Comment: It didn´t solve. 
I think i have to use this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/testrail-promise". I'm trying to set it up

Comment: Well, I don't know Testrail so gl.

Answer (score 0):

Try promise chaining which helps you to get the status of the `it` and also the `catch` at the end will help to analyze on the failures.

```
`it('&*&*&**&', (done: DoneFn) => {
                .then(() => expect()
                .then(() => expect()
                .then(() => done());
        });`
```

Refer for more details https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/

Hope this helps you!!

## 0506

Comment: I fixed it with testrail-promisse.

Comment: Cool. Promise method varied from platform to platform. The answer suggested to you was of jasmine promise chaining